# Goodbye - is it very formal?

Tags: american-english, british-english, writing-style, register

I'm writing about cultural differences - not for scientific purposes - and am trying to find out about more and less formal ways of saying goodbye in English.

- On a scale of formality (from least to most formal), where would you put "goodbye", "bye-bye", "bye", "take care" and "cheers"?
- What would you use in a formal context (e.g. business meeting with 'important' people in the company/decision-makers, etc.)?

I'm mostly interested in answers relating to American and British English, but any other varieties are welcome as well.

Comment: You're missing "farewell" (do people use it anymore?), "tata", "ciao".

Comment: I haven't heard "farewell" in spoken English, and "tata" is more of a dialect/regional thing, isn't it?. Is "ciao" also used a lot (we use it in German, too).

Comment: "Goodbye" can sound quite formal, depending on HOW it is said.  "Bye-bye" (sometimes pronounced bub eye'), "bye" and "take care" are more informal than formal.  Just make sure NOT to say "See ya later, alligator" or "In a while, crocodile" in a formal setting!

Comment: Speaking as an American, I'd say "cheers" is also a dialect thing (it's certainly not American), and I hear it a lot less than "ciao".

Comment: In the UK 'taraa', also shortened to 'tra' is very common, informally.

Answer (score 3):

British English native speaker: Out of those options, I'd put *goodbye* most formal, followed by *bye* and *take care* around equal, then *bye-bye*. *Cheers* is a synonym for *thanks*, and I wouldn't use it as a salutation.

In the context you've described (not sure I'd call it 'formal'; perhaps 'business' or something like that), probably something like *bye*, *goodbye*, *take care*, *good to meet you*, *see you soon*, *thanks for taking the time* etc..

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I've heard "cheers" a lot when I lived in Wales, could it be a regional thing?

Comment: Well, I can imagine it used when leaving someone, to mean *thanks for meeting me* or suchlike. But I wouldn't call it a synonym for *goodbye*.

Comment: @pasacasa   'Cheers' is often used to sign off emails (informally), not necessarily as 'thanks'. I've seen this in Wales, though I don't know if it's common elsewhere.